# Error in php class with predefined values?

Tags: php, class

In my PHP file I have created a class as below but I am getting error on line 3rd and 5th line.

```
class CommonPath{
    var $baseurl = 'http://mysite.com/';
    var $docroot = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    var $root = '/';
    var $images = $this->root.'/img';           
}
```

My Dreamwaver CS5 showing these lines (3rd & 5th) as erroneous lines and I am getting following error on executing this code.

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';'' in D:\wamp\www\site\libs\CommonPath.php on line 3
```

Comment: Could you add the error as well?

Comment: Please **always** add the exact error message. With 175 questions under your belt, that should go without saying.

Comment: Exact error added, and guys please accept my apologies, will take care this in future & add errors in questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign the values like that right when you're declaring your member properties. Assign it in the constructor

```
class CommonPath{
    var $baseurl = 'http://mysite.com/';
    var $docroot = '';
    var $root = '/';
    var $images = '';

    function __construct() {
        $this->docroot  = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));;
        $this->images = $this->root.'/img';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ironically, you could do: `define('CommonPath_DocRoot', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))); class CommonPath { var $docroot = CommonPath_DocRoot;` ...

Comment: This is because the constant is already defined and is the same as assigning a fixed variable to the property

Answer (score 7):

You can have only literals and constants as default values. No functions or other expressions are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different mistakes. First, you cannot use functions to define class variables (line 3). Moreover, `$this` does not make sense in line 5, as you have got no object yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can not `concat` string and assign any value to variable which need to call any function, at the time declaring class variable.